# Search bar in Laravel 5.3 to filter the table

Tags: php, html, laravel, search, laravel-blade

1) I added the search bar to the view :

```
{!! Form::open(['method'=>'GET','url'=>'home','class'=>'navbar-form navbar-left','role'=>'search'])  !!}

            <div class="input-group custom-search-form">
                <input type="text" class="form-control" name="search" placeholder="Search...">
                <span class="input-group-btn">
    <button class="btn btn-default-sm" type="submit">
        <i class="fa fa-search">i
    </button>
</span>
```

2) In my controller I'm displaying all my users in a table and the search bar is on top of it

```
public function index()
{
    $user = User::all();

    $search = \Request::get('search');  the param of URI

    $users = User::where('name','=','%'.$search.'%')
        ->orderBy('name')
        ->paginate(20);

    return view('home',compact('users'))->withuser($user);

}
```

Here is what the table looks like

```
 @foreach($user as $users)
                    <th scope="row">1</th>
                     <td><a href="{{ url('/user').'/'.$users->id }}">show</a></td>
                      <td>{{$users->name}}</td>
                    <td>{{$users->city}}</td>
                    <td>{{$users->phone}}</td>
                    <td>{{$users->street}}</td>
                    <td>{{$users->national_id}}</td>
                    <td>{{$users->name}}</td>

                </tr>
     @endforeach
```

What I'm trying to get is when I search in the bar I want to do a loop like this 
       @foreach($users as $user)
           
            {{ $user->name }}
            
        @endforeach
and replace the view to the searched names only. 
and here is the route for the index

```
    Route::get('/home', 'HomeController@index');
```

how can I achive that ? sorry for the long question in advance.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You need to use `like` instead of `=`:

```
$users = User::where('name', 'like', '%'.$search.'%')
    ->orderBy('name')
    ->paginate(20);
```

Also, you're trying to create two queries. Much better way is to create [local scope](https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/eloquent#local-scopes):

```
public function scopeSearch($q)
{
    return empty(request()->search) ? $q : $q->where('name', 'like', '%'.request()->search.'%');
}
```

And then use it in controller:

```
public function index()
{
    $users = User::search()->orderBy('name')->paginate(20);

    return view('home', compact('users'));
}
```

This code will paginate all users if there is no search parameter or it will filter users and paginate them.

Comment: hi there, how about my html ? Do I have to add anything more for `users` ? because I fixed everything but the search bar does not filter users yet @Alexey Mezenin

Comment: It should be `@foreach($users as $user)` and `$user->name`, `$user->city` etc.